# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'testimonypost' not found. 'testimonypost' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

I can't figure this out. I have tried different things to no avail. Commenting out to app_name in my urls.py gets me to the page perfectly. Is there something i should know about the app_name?
Any ideas?
The views.py is attached below. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
 #models.py
    class Testimony(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse("Testimony:details", kwargs={"id": self.id} )

    #urls.py
    app_name='Testimony'
    urlpatterns=[
    path('testimonypost/', views.TestimonyOrderView, name='testimonypost'),]


    #template(traceback points to this line)
    <li><a href="{% url 'testimonypost'%}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain">&nbspTestimonies</a></li>

#views.py
def TestimonyOrderView(request):
    queryset_list=Testimony.objects.annotate().order_by('timestamp')

    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 20)
    page_request_var="page"
    page=request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset=paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
            queryset=paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset=paginator.page(paginator_num.pages)


    return render(request, 'testimony_post.html', {'queryset_list':queryset_list})
```

Comment: `views.TestimonyOrderView.as_view()`

Comment: I believe you are referring to  class in models.py. I have just added the views.py for clearer illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url part in your template is wrong. It must be : `{% url 'Testimony:testimonypost' %}`
After you've used namespaces, you must use the app name in your urls.

See this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls

Comment: Great ! Glad it worked. Can you please accept it as the answer ?